# PHP Pass variable to next page after dynamic dropbox selected

Tags: php, sql

I created the following code,which enables the dropdown to get all the values from sql db, its able to get the dropdown values,but I am not able to selected value to next php page

```
  <?php
$link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxxxxx.com', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", $link);

function print_dropdown($query)
{
$queried = mysql_query($query);
$menu = '<select name="Topic">';
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
$topic = htmlspecialchars($result['topic']);
$menu .= '<option value="' . $topic .'">' . $topic . '</option>';
}
$menu .= '</select>';
return $menu;
}


echo print_dropdown("SELECT topic FROM learning_outcome");
?>
```

i used session and cache to send the selected value from dropdown,but output is empty in next page

Comment: `i used session and cache to send the selected value from dropdown` how are you doing this?

Comment: Session:

//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];


Cookie:

//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];

Comment: fixed by using $_POST['Topic']

Answer (score 0):

fixed by using  $_POST['Topic']